# Query Optimization with millions of row in table

Tags: sql, database-performance

i have a table which has 4 columns

PKID,OutMailID,JobMailingDate,InsertDatetime
This is how the data ot inserted into the table 
PKID is the primary Key of the table
for a single outMailID with JObMailingDate there are on avg 3 records are present in the table with
different insert date time. The table is having millions of records

I have many other table which has the same data but those is partaining to different category

Now i would like to find out the
1) Find All OutMailID Whose InsertDatetime is in between the Parameter data range 
2) Once i have the list of OutMailID I would Like to Find the Minimum InsertDatetime for all these OutMailID Where this min Date falls between Param 1 and Param2

The Data for the table is like this

```
Select 1 as PKID,1 as OutMailID,'2010/01/01' as JobMailingDate,'2010/01/01' as InsertDatetime 
UNION ALL

Select 2 as PKID,1 as OutMailID,'2010/01/01' as JobMailingDate,'2010/01/02' as InsertDatetime 
UNION ALL

Select 3 as PKID,1 as OutMailID,'2010/01/01' as JobMailingDate,'2010/01/03' as InsertDatetime 
UNION ALL

Select 4 as PKID,1 as OutMailID,'2010/01/01' as JobMailingDate,'2010/01/04' as InsertDatetime
```

All the above 2 steps i want to perform in a single Query so my query is somethig like this

```
Select 
    OutMailID,Min(InsertDatetime)
from 
    Table T
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        Select 
            OutMailID
        from 
            Table 
        Where 
            InsertDatetime Between @Param1 and @Param2
    ) as T1 On (T1.OutMailID = T.outMailID)
Group by 
    OutMailID
Having Min(InsertDatetime) Between Between @Param1 and @Param2
```

But this is not Performing well. can anyone please suggest me a good way of doing this

The second problem is that once i have the output of first query then i use the same above query for other category to find out the min InsertDatatime in that category and once i have all the min date for all the category then i have to find the Min insert date among all the category

Can you please help me on this

Thanks
Atul

Comment: I would go with `with` statement to perform better performance on this

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  As one might suspect, the actual engine is important as a performance consideration.

Comment: You should also add the definition of the tables involved (as `create table` statements) all indexes defined (as `create index`)  and the execution plan (as plain text please, screenshots hide too much detail)

Answer (score 0):

How about using on this `with` statement, the `with` is like views that keeps everything in cache to have it for later, here is an example

```
with Table1 as (
   Select OutMailID from Table Where InsertDatetime Between @Param1 and @Param2 
),
Table2 as (
   Select 4 as PKID,1 as OutMailID,'2010/01/01' as JobMailingDate,'2010/01/04' as InsertDatetime
)
select * from Table as T
inner join Table1 as T1 on T1.OutMailID = T.outMailID
group by T.OutMailID
```

That way you can reuse the `Table1` multiple times without re-querying it again.

Comment: Since i have to perform the same step with different category also so having all the 3 category table in the with tablle clause would make query very slow because the CTE is llike an inline query

Comment: You can do multiple with table clause's that would perform everything as once and shouldn't be a problem with performance,  I'm not sure what the other categories are but I update my answer based on what I understand you want to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Does this query give you the desired results?

Select T.OutMailID, Min(T.InsertDatetime) 
from Table T 
INNER JOIN Table T1 On T1.OutMailID = T.outMailID
    And T2.InsertDatetime Between @Param1 and @Param2
Group by OutMailID

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler way to express your requirement is that you want all `OutMailId` whose first `InsertDateTime` is in the period specified.

It turns out that the `JOIN` is not necessary at all for this.  This is a simpler version of your query:

```
Select t.OutMailID, Min(InsertDatetime)
from Table T
Group by OutMailID
Having Min(InsertDatetime) Between @Param1 and @Param2;
```

Many databases could take advantage of an index on `Table(OutMailId, InsertDateTime)` for this query.

Now, this query might not be super efficient, particularly if the range is small relative to the entire data.  So, sticking with the above index, the following might work better:

```
select t.*
from (select OutMailId, min(InsertDatetime) as min_InsertDatetime
      from table t
      where InsertDatetime Between @Param1 and @Param2
      group by OutMailId
     ) t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.OutMailId = t.OutMailId and
                        t2.InsertDateTime < @Param1
                 );
```

This should use the index for the first subquery, limiting the number of ids.  It should use the same index for the `not exists`, on a reduced number of rows.